# Can I restore the previous previous session in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I opened about 200 tabs of webpages in Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04.

I closed Firefox, and then rebooted Ubuntu.

When I started Firefox again, I had a chance to restore the previous 200 tabs of webpages, by clicking History->Restore Previous Session. But instead of doing that, I clicked a new tab and opened a newpage, and closed the tab, which closed Firefox out of my expectation (in Chrome browser, closing the only tab doesn't close the Chrome browser).

Now clicking History->Restore Previous Session only restore the single tab of webpage. Is there some way to restore the previous previous session of 200 tabs of webpages?

Note that it seems to me difficult to find out the previous previous 200 webpages' URLs from most recent history in Firefox. The previous previous session of 200 tabs of webpages were also created by clicking History->Restore Previous Session, and Firefox doesn't actually open all the 200 webpages when I restored it, but open each webpage when I actually click its tab, and I didn't click all of the 200 tabs.

Comment: I think there might be an answer somewhere in the profile's files, but for next time consider an add-on like [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) - *"Session Manager saves and restores the state of all or some windows - either when you want it or automatically at startup and after crashes. It can also automatically save the state of open windows individually."*

Comment: @Xen2050 "Not compatible with Firefox Quantum"

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought that message might've been because of my Chromium, but their About blurb sounds like Firefox just permanently took away support for anything similar... disappointing. "*Unfortunately do to limitations in the the provided APIs in Firefox 57, Session Manager cannot be implemented as a WebExtension add-on and will not work in Firefox 57 or higher. My only recommendation is to either not update to Firefox 57, use the Firefox ESR build or use a forked version of Firefox that does not remove support for add-ons such as CyberFox or Waterfox.*"

Comment: @Tim, if you want to avoid this predicament in the future, there's a setting that controls whether closing the last tab also closes the window.  Open `about:config` and find `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`.  The default setting is `true`.  Change it to `false`.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the late response, I just faced the same problem with Firefox 78: I closed firefox window by mistake while it was still starting up, and all my 200+ opened tabs were gone :(

I'm pasting the right procedure here for future reference, but **all credits go to Martin Brinkmann from Ghacks: [How to restore Firefox sessions if Session Restore is not working correctly](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/06/03/how-to-restore-firefox-sessions-if-session-restore-is-not-working-correctly/)**:

I solved following these steps:

1. Close the Firefox browser. Make sure no instance of the browser is running.
2. Open the profile folder and rename the current session file *sessionstore.jsonlz4* to *sessionstore-backup.jsonlz4*.
3. Open the *sessionstore-backups* folder of the profile.
4. Rename *recovery.jsonlz4* to *recovery-backup.jsonlz4*.
5. Rename *recovery.backlz4* to *recovery-backup.backlz4*.
6. Copy the session restore backup that you want to restore, e.g. *previous.jsonlz4*.
7. Go back to the root directory of the Firefox profile.
8. Paste the copied file to the root folder.
9. Rename it to *sessionstore.jsonlz4*.
10. Restart the Firefox browser.
11. Firefox might pick up the session automatically. If it does not, press the Alt-key on your keyboard and select History > Restore Previous Session.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to click on 200 shortcuts:

- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to view the complete *History*.
- Select a series of URL's by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click or select items one-at-a-time by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click.
- Right-click on an item and select `Open all in tabs`.

[image: Firefox Library Dialog]

For future reference, you can tag *Bookmarks* to make searching and loading a batch easier.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is how to find out which the 200 URLs in the previous previous session are.

Comment: If a tab was just sitting there for weeks (un-viewed / un-clicked) I don't think it would get put in the history every day, so might have some digging to do but at least they should all be there, some*time*

Comment: He means he didnt click each tab, it has nothing to do with multiple select and opening, but with the fact that an "open" does not load until you actually click on it (to save resources I guess)